# Using Angular 2 in Chrome packaged app

Tags: angular, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to create a chrome packaged app using Angular 2. But I'm getting the following error when I try to run my app:

> EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource
>
> -> Evaluating chrome-extension://aabbecghjjmmpbagelfmhllgaidcbnmn/app/boot.js

The content of `boot.js` is:

```
System.config({ packages: { app: { format: 'register', defaultExtension: 'js', "defaultJSExtensions": true, } } });
System.import('app/boot').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

I know AngularJS (angular 1) had an `ng-csp` directive to fix this `Content Security Policy` error. Is there something similair for Angular 2?

Is there a way to run Angular 2 in a packaged app?

Comment: See https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1744 and https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5956

Comment: @EricMartinez I've seen both Github topics before. The first one provides "a way" to possible fix this issue by using `bind(ChangeDetector)...`, but things have changed since then. I'm not sure how to do that in the `beta8` version. The second link makes me think that Angular 2 isn't ready for Chrome Packaged Apps?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the short answer to solving the issue.

Add the following to you Chrome Extension or App Manifest.json

"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

tldr;

Chrome Developer - Extension
Content Security Policy (CSP)
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy

[image]

Here's the answer from GitHub

CSP in chrome app with angular 2 #5956
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5956#issuecomment-180135425
[image]

Here's the issue describe in AngularJS
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCsp
[image]

Comment: No, this is only for chrome EXTENSIONS, the question was about PACKAGED APPS.

Answer (score 1):

So your error message shows that `eval` is the issue.  Are you using Just-in-Time compilation for your Angular 2 app?  I realize this is an old question, but if you use AOT (Ahead-of-Time) compilation, it will not need to use `eval` for your templates:

https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler

> Better security
>
> AOT compiles HTML templates and components into JavaScript files long
>   before they are served to the client. With no templates to read and no
>   risky client-side HTML or JavaScript evaluation, there are fewer
>   opportunities for injection attacks.

Another option is to use `<webview>` to host your Angular 2 app:
https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview

With this, the content of your page will not be sandboxed and the CSP requirements of a Chrome App will not apply.  However, you will not be able to access the Chrome App APIs directly from your Angular app.  The solution to this is to use message passing between your Angular app and the Chrome App that is hosting it.  The Angular app sends a message to host, and host invokes Chrome App API and sends results back to Angular app page:

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_external#postMessage

Answer (score 0):

make packing in one application file using SystemJS Build https://github.com/systemjs/builder.

Then add it to the index.html, so

```
<script src="angular2-polyfills.js"></script> 
<script src="app.min.js" ></script>
```

You can fixed

EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource

using sandbox in manifest.json https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/sandbox

Comment: Were you actually able to get an angular application to run in no-eval mode? I've tried many different methods, but don't want to go down the system-builder path unless you've had success previously

Answer (score -1):

You can see this bug issues in Angular 2

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5956

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.